# Shell script to decrypt and move files from one directory to another directory

Tags: shell, encryption

I have a directory and in it has several files.  I'm trying to decrypt those files and move them to another directory.  I can't figure out how to set the output filename and move it.

So, the directory structure looks like the following:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/decryptandmove.sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/passtext.txt
/Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted/test1.txt.pgp
/Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted/test2.txt.pgp
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/decrypted/
```

For all the files that are found in the encrypted directory, I'm trying to decrypt them and then move them to the directory www/decrypted/.  I don't know what the filenames in the encrypted directory will be ahead of time (this script will eventually run via cron job), so I wanted to just output the decrypted files with the same filenames, but without the pgp.  So, the result would be:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/decryptandmove.sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/passtext.txt
/Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted/
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/decrypted/test1.txt.pgp
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/decrypted/test2.txt.pgp
```

So, this is all I have written so far and it doesn't work.  FILE and FILENAME are both wrong.  I haven't even gotten to the moving part.

```
pass_phrase=`cat passtext.txt|awk '{print $1}'`

for FILE in '/Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted/';
 do
    FILENAME=$(basename $FILE .pgp) 
    gpg --passphrase $pass_phrase --output $FILENAME --decrypt $FILE
 done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
p=$(<passtext.txt)
set -- $p
pass_phrase=$1
destination="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/decrypted/"
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted
for FILE in *.pgp;
do
    FILENAME=${FILE%.pgp}
    gpg --passphrase "$pass_phrase" --output "$destination/$FILENAME" --decrypt "$FILE"
done
```

Comment: I've been trying to use this, but I keep getting:

gpg: /Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted/: read error: Is a directory
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you very much.  I totally don't understand most of the syntax, but I'll definitely try to figure out what it all means...

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the FILENAME and FILE problems, although it will only work if you're in the "decrypted" directory right now. If you want to fix that you'll have to add the correct directory to the FILENAME variable :)

```
pass_phrase=`cat passtext.txt|awk '{print $1}'`

for FILE in /Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted/*; do
    FILENAME=$(basename $FILE .pgp) 
    gpg --passphrase $pass_phrase --output $FILENAME --decrypt $FILE
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do a `cd` first:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/encrypted/
```

Then

```
for FILE in $(ls); do ...
```

or

```
for FILE in `ls`; do ...
```

I personally prefer:

```
ls | while read FILE; do ...
```

Then maybe

```
cd -
```

*Important:* If you use the `ls` approach, make sure that your filenames don't contain spaces. See also the link in ghostdog74's comment (thanks, BTW) - this page is generally quite useful.

Comment: @ghostdog74: Maybe you're right, but using ls has some advantages: 1) You don't have to use basename to get rid of the unnecessary path. 2) You can use all the options of ls, and even pipe it through other tools before using the values.

Comment: using `ls` in a for loop has no advantages at all. you fork another process and its prone to error if file names has white spaces. As for 2), you did not use `ls -l`, so there are no options to talk about

Comment: I know. Still, I need it for my scripts to sort files by date. How would you do that?