# GnuPG Shell Script - Refuses to read password

Tags: shell, ubuntu, passwords, gnupg

The script below used to work on Mac OS X, but, since moving it to Ubuntu, it doesn't seem to read from the password file at all.  Even when I run it from the command line, no matter what I do, I get a popup prompt asking me for the password.  As this will run via cron, I don't want this to happen...  I want it to read the password from the file with no prompt.  To note, I did try using passphrase-fd and passphrase-file, neither of which worked...

```
#!/bin/sh
p=$(<pass.txt)
set -- $p
pass_phrase=$1
destination="/var/www/decrypted"
cd /var/sl_bin/
for FILE in *.pgp;
do
    FILENAME=${FILE%.pgp}
    gpg --passphrase "$pass_phrase" --output "$destination/$FILENAME" --decrypt "$FILE"
    rm -f $FILE
done
```

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
gpg --no-use-agent --batch --passphrase-file pass.txt --output kkkk.tar.bz2  --decrypt kkk-data.tar.bz2.gpg
```

Answer (score 3):

The `--passphrase-file` option seems to be broken / not honored. I had to use `--passphrase-fd 0` instead, like so:

```
cat .password | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output foo --decrypt foo.gpg
```

Comment: Yes, I could not get --passphrase-file to work either while -passphrase-fd worked.

Comment: It works combined with `--no-use-agent --batch`. Interestingly, `--passphrase` works without those two options.

Answer (score 2):

Use option *--no-use-agent*. It won't prompt you using option *--passphrase*.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to supply the file via standard input (eg, because you're plugging this into another command like git, which wants to supply the content to sign via standard input), then you can use another file descriptor:

```
gpg --passphrase-fd 3 <your command here> 3< pass.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that `$passphrase` is null. On Ubuntu `sh` is symlinked to `dash` which doesn't understand `$(<file_name)` in the same way that Bash does (but doesn't issue an error either).

You can change your shebang to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or use `$(cat pass.txt)`

Also, why not combine the second, third and fourth lines?: `pass_phrase=$(<pass.txt)` (or `pass_phrase=($(<pass.txt))` if you're trying to strip off all but the first "word" in the file).

<sup>[Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512503/shell-script-to-decrypt-and-move-files-from-one-directory-to-another)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

as your first line instead of `#!/bin/sh`

As for your pass phrase problem, you should probably try to use some automatic mechanism. check the gpg documentation for information. I don't use gpg, but you can check out `gpg-agent`.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions (the first one solved my problem ;-))

- http://www.roguedaemon.net/rephrase/
- gpg uses --passphrase-fd not --passphrase

  echo yourpw|gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output out.txt -d file.txt

Answer (score 0):

You're getting password prompt because you have `DISPLAY` variable set (if you click cancel the script will continue decrypting files). `DISPLAY` shouldn't be set in the cron environment, so you can probably ignore it, but to be sure or be able to test the script from command prompt add

```
unset DISPLAY
```

to the beginning of the script or run it before executing.

Also to be able to use `$(<file)` syntax you need to change

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You should avoid using `--passphrase` option which could lead to revealing your password on multi-user system. You can use `--passphrase-file` instead. Here's how I would change your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PASSFILE=$(pwd)/pass.txt
destination="/var/www/decrypted"
cd /var/sl_bin/
for FILE in *.pgp;
do
    FILENAME=${FILE%.pgp}
    gpg --passphrase-file $PASSFILE --output "$destination/$FILENAME" --decrypt "$FILE"
    rm -f $FILE
done
```

To save location of the password file before changing current directory, I saved it in `PASSFILE` variable.

Answer (score 0):

add `--archive` to read password from `--passphrase-file`

Answer (score 0):

You must to use:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 1 --passphrase-file your_password_file -c your_file_to_encript.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below script

```
#! /bin/sh
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase='PASSWORD' --output /output/outputFileName /input/inputFileName
```