# Automatically sign build artifact from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gnupg

I'm writing a library that uses cmake. I've set the build up to add a `make` target that builds a Debian source package that I can then upload to Launchpad with `dput` to create an Ubuntu PPA. Part of this process is signing the package with my `gpg` key. When I run this `make` target while logged into a normal X session it pops up a box that asks me for my `gpg` passphrase.

I want to have Jenkins do this automatically to upload a daily snapshot build. The question is how to get Jenkins to sign the package automatically. I've seen similar questions but they never really answered what I'm looking for.

I assume I need to run `gpg-agent` to handle this but here are the things I don't understand:

1.) Jenkins runs under the `jenkins` user. How do I get `gpg-agent` running for this user. I've seen that `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)` can be put in a shell script startup file but that wouldn't get sourced by Jenkins.

2.) How do I make `gpg-agent` aware of my passphrase. If I log in to the `jenkins` user with `sudo su - jenkins` I can use `gpg` to decrypt a file but it pops up `pinentry-curses` and asks for my passphrase. How would this be handled from Jenkins. I'd like to enter my passphrase once and have it remembered.

Answer (score 0):

1) Could you use the absolute path to the `gpg-agent`? Maybe I did not get you right..

2) You should use `--passphrase-fd 0` as an argument to gpg (like that: `echo password | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt / --encrypt`). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530458/gnupg-shell-script-refuses-to-read-password).